# How can I run ubuntu running of a live USB and get it to keep all my data and not be really slow

Tags: live-usb

How can I get Ubuntu to run off a USB drive but on shutdown it keeps all my data intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Ubuntu installed on your pc, you can use the Startup Disk Creator that is already preinstalled. It has the option to store documents and settings in a reserved space, of which you can define the size. It won't be as fast as a normal install when using USB2 (I'm not sure about USB3), but it will be fast enough once Ubuntu has been loaded into your RAM, for me at least.